# Issue in opening a module in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I'm trying to use the "Batteries" module, but... it doesnt work!

Here is an example:

```
open Batteries;;

print_endline (dump [5;4;2]);;
```

I'm compiling with: `opam exec ocamlc main.ml` the error message is:

```
File "main.ml", line 1, characters 5-14:
1 | open Batteries;;
         ^^^^^^^^^
Error: Unbound module Batteries
```

and the Batteries module seems installed:

```
$ opam install Batteries
[NOTE] Package batteries is already installed (current version is 3.0.0).
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just installing a library is not enough, you have to tell the compiler that you want to link it (the compiler itself doesn't know anything about opam). There are many compilation and configuration tools available for OCaml, here's just one of the ways to build a binary that uses batteries

```
ocamlbuild -pkg batteries main.native
```

Comment: thaks for the answer. However, I cannot run it under the "opam exec" command. 
```$ opam exec ocamlbuild -pkg batteries main.native
opam: unknown option `-p'.
```
adding quotes doesnt change the output

Comment: nevermind, I've just find it out: I need a double dash between exec and the actual command!

Comment: yes, you can do `opam exec -- ocamlbuild -pkg batteries main.native` but a more common approach is to enable your opam switch with one `eval $(opam env)` command and then you don't need to use `opam exec` at all. If you're using Emacs, then there is an `opam-env` command in the Tuareg mode that will do the same for the Emacs environment.